# NestJS new project with yarn : Failed to execute command: yarn install --silent

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nestjs, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to use yarn to install a new NestJs project .

1. Windows version : Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19044.3086]
2. Node version : 18.17.1
3. npm version : 9.6.7
4. yarn version : 1.22.19
5. Nest cli version : 10.1.16

I tried to install using : `npm install --global yarn` and i also tried to install windows installer : https://classic.yarnpkg.com/latest.msi

I tried to create a new project :

```
nest new task_management
```

I'm always getting this error :

[image]

[image]

I tried :

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
yarn global add @nestjs/cli
```

I tried to reinstall node, but i still get the same error !

Comment: Did you do a yarn install like it suggested?

Comment: yes and i didn't get all  default NestJS folders and files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a yarn cache problem

this resolve the problem for me :

```
yarn cache clean
nest new task_management
```